# Is there a desktop widget / Windows sidebar widget for adding new tasks to Teamplain

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

Just wondered if there is a widget for quickly adding tasks to Teamplain.

I'm keeping track of all tasks that come in, including anything for adding a new AD user, up to changes to existing systems, new requests etc.

For the simpler tasks i'd like a quick way of adding one. Perhaps there is an outlook plugin that works with Outlook Tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is to just use the interface built into Visual Studio.

What I was looking for was something where I could set a template for regular things that I log, and then quickly add one.

Doesn't seem to be anything that does exactly this so I just use VS interface. Easy enough.